# Uninitialised Constant Doorkeeper::AccessToken in Doorkeeper Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, grape-api, doorkeeper

I've implemented OAuth 2 with Doorkeeper Gem in a rails project(Grape API). I want to delete the *expired* and *revoked* `access_token` by a rake task. So far, I've been following the official doorkeeper documentation and stumble upon [rake task](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#rake-tasks). According to it, I added `Doorkeeper::Rake.load_tasks` in my `Rakefile`. After that when I run `rake doorkeeper:db:cleanup` in console, I get the following error.

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Doorkeeper::AccessToken
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0p0/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0p0/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0p0/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0p0/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:56:in `load_missing_constant'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0p0/ruby/2.6.0/gems/doorkeeper-5.0.2/lib/doorkeeper/rake/db.rake:16:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
```

My *Rakefile.rb*

```
require_relative 'config/application'
Doorkeeper::Rake.load_tasks
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

I've also read [Cleanup AccessGrant and AccessToken](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/500) and [Add a rake task to cleanup stale database records](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/pull/1068) but none of this solves my issue. How can I solve this?

**Update**
*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0p0/ruby/2.6.0/gems/doorkeeper-5.0.2/lib/doorkeeper.rb* file

```
require 'doorkeeper/version'
require 'doorkeeper/engine'
require 'doorkeeper/config'

require 'doorkeeper/request/strategy'
require 'doorkeeper/request/authorization_code'
require 'doorkeeper/request/client_credentials'
require 'doorkeeper/request/code'
require 'doorkeeper/request/password'
require 'doorkeeper/request/refresh_token'
require 'doorkeeper/request/token'

require 'doorkeeper/errors'
require 'doorkeeper/server'
require 'doorkeeper/request'
require 'doorkeeper/validations'

require 'doorkeeper/oauth/authorization/code'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/authorization/context'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/authorization/token'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/authorization/uri_builder'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/helpers/scope_checker'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/helpers/uri_checker'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/helpers/unique_token'

require 'doorkeeper/oauth'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/scopes'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/error'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/base_response'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/code_response'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/token_response'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/error_response'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/pre_authorization'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/base_request'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/authorization_code_request'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/refresh_token_request'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/password_access_token_request'

require 'doorkeeper/oauth/client_credentials/validation'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/client_credentials/creator'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/client_credentials/issuer'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/client_credentials/validation'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/client/credentials'

require 'doorkeeper/oauth/client_credentials_request'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/code_request'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/token_request'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/client'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/token'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/token_introspection'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/invalid_token_response'
require 'doorkeeper/oauth/forbidden_token_response'

require 'doorkeeper/models/concerns/orderable'
require 'doorkeeper/models/concerns/scopes'
require 'doorkeeper/models/concerns/expirable'
require 'doorkeeper/models/concerns/revocable'
require 'doorkeeper/models/concerns/accessible'

require 'doorkeeper/models/access_grant_mixin'
require 'doorkeeper/models/access_token_mixin'
require 'doorkeeper/models/application_mixin'

require 'doorkeeper/helpers/controller'

require 'doorkeeper/rails/routes'
require 'doorkeeper/rails/helpers'

require 'doorkeeper/rake'
require 'doorkeeper/stale_records_cleaner'

require 'doorkeeper/orm/active_record'

module Doorkeeper
  def self.authenticate(request, methods = Doorkeeper.configuration.access_token_methods)
    OAuth::Token.authenticate(request, *methods)
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like it's problem of `require` ordering, I guess. Have you tried editing the order of `doorkeeper` in `/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0p0/ruby/2.6.0/gems/doorkeeper-5.0.2/lib/doorkeeper.rb` ?. Currently, `doorkeeper` is required before `doorkeeper/orm/active_record` which includes `Doorkeeper::AccessToken`

Comment: @Hoa.Nguyen Thank for your comment. I've updated my answer. Can you please tell me exactly which ordering you are referring to change in that file?

Comment: Let's try to move `doorkeeper/orm/active_record` to before `doorkeeper/rake`

Comment: @Hoa.Nguyen I've just done so, but still it's a no go. :(

Comment: hmm, it's weird. With the same ruby version and doorkeeper version, my laptop is still good to go. Have you run all the command in its README? `rails generate doorkeeper:install` or `rails generate doorkeeper:migration`. I guess yes, right?

Comment: @Hoa.Nguyen Yeah, It is fully functional. Just not the rake task. :( Looks like I'll have to run a custom query to delete those expired and revoked tokens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189387/discussion-between-user5756014-and-hoa-nguyen).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to load application env first for your rake task?

Doorkeeper models uses lazy-loading with ActiveSupport hooks (`on_load(:active_record`), so if you don't load your app env or AR it can skip models initialization and that's why Rake task misses required classes.